# C# remove null values from object array

Tags: c#, arrays

I got an array of a specific object. Lets say the object Car. At some point in my code I need to remove all Car-objects from this array that do not fulfill the requirements I stated. This leaves null values in the array.

```
public class Car{
    public string type { get; set; }

    public Car(string ntype){
        this.type = ntype;
    }
}

Car[] cars = new Car[]{ new Car("Mercedes"), new Car("BMW"), new Car("Opel");

//This should function remove all cars from the array where type is BMW.
cars = removeAllBMWs(cars);

//Now Cars has become this.
Cars[0] -> Car.type = Mercedes
Cars[1] -> null
Cars[2] -> Car.type = Opel

//I want it to become this.
Cars[0] -> Car.type = Mercedes
Cars[1] -> Car.type = Opel
```

Of course my real code is far more complex than this, but the base idea is the same. My question that I have is: How can I remove the empty values from this array?

I found countless solutions for a string array, but none for an object array.

Comment: *"I found countless solutions for a string array, but none for an object array"* - pretty sure they'll work for `Car` as well as they work for `string`...

Comment: they all use string.isemptyornull

Comment: So just replace that with `== null`.

Comment: Why not just use a `list` instead of an array? then you wont have any nulls

Comment: Why does `removeAllBMWs` set them `null` instead of removing them in the first place? Instead it could create the new array in this way: `cars.Where(c => c.type == "BMW").ToArray()` which makes the method redundant.

Comment: @Sayse I receive the array from a webservice of course converting it to a list is possible but the array can contain a lot of values and converting to a list might cause some performance issues. Speed has high priority in the application that I am building.

Comment: @kpp - You seem to have written the `removeAllBMWs` method yourself (or your team has) so I'd say just make that return a list since you are already modifying the array

Comment: This question is more about not processing specific elements of an array than it is about removing nulls.  The OP would be far better off not self-imposing nulls in the first place.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The following will create a new array with all the null values excluded (which seems to be what you actually want?):

```
Cars = Cars.Where(c => c != null).ToArray();
```

Better yet, define your `RemoveAllBMWs` method to omit the BMWs in the first place instead of setting them to null:

```
internal static Car[] RemoveAllBMWs(IEnumerable<Car> cars)
{
    return cars.Where(c => c != null && c.Type != "BMW").ToArray();
}
```

Comment: But the question is why he first uses a method `removeAllBMWs` which modifies the array in a way that it assigns `null` to every BMW. You could do both in one with `cars.Where(c => c.type == "BMW").ToArray()`

Comment: @TimSchmelter, this is a simplified version. I do not personally instantiate the array I receive it via a webservice from another application. Not all values in this array are useful though.

Comment: @TimSchmelter True, though I think you meant `!=`, not `==`. I've added an addendum.